# DI ConfigService inside custom logger module not reading env properties in test, but works

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I have a logger module that exports a custom logger which is imported into app module. It uses ConfigService to read an env variable to turn on/off logs. This works fine when running the app, however, the ConfigService returns undefined in testing and so logs are printed in test (which I don't want).

I can solve this by doing this instead, but I want to understand why configService does not work

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'dev-test') this.setLogLevels([]);
```

```js
// src/log/log.service.ts

@Injectable()
export class LogService extends ConsoleLogger {
  constructor(private readonly CONFIG: ConfigService) {
    super();
    console.log('LOGS:', this.CONFIG.get('LOGS'));
    if (this.CONFIG.get('LOGS') === 'false') this.setLogLevels([]);
  }
}
```

```js
// src/log/log.module.ts

@Module({
  providers: [LogService],
  exports: [LogService]
})
export class LogModule {}
```

```js
// src/app/app.module.ts

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: `env/.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
      isGlobal: true
    }),
    LogModule
  ],
  controllers: [AppController]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

```js
// src/app/app.controller.spec.ts

describe('AppController', () => {
  let appController: AppController;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const app: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [AppController],
      providers: [ConfigService, LogService]
    }).compile();

    appController = app.get<AppController>(AppController);
  });

  describe('getHello()', () => {
    it('should return "Hello World!"', () => {
      expect(appController.getHello()).toBe('Hello World!');
    });
  });

  describe('getEnvironment()', () => {
    it('should return the current env name', () => {
      expect(appController.getEnvironment()).toBe('dev-test');
    });
  });
});
```